# Can't get full table from requests python

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the whole table from this website: https://br.investing.com/commodities/aluminum-historical-data

But when I send this code:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
r = s.post('https://br.investing.com/commodities/aluminum-historical-data',
                 headers={"curr_id": "49768","smlID": "300586","header": "Alumínio Futuros Dados Históricos",
                          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'st_date': '01/01/2017','end_date': '29/09/2018',
                         'interval_sec': 'Daily','sort_col': 'date','sort_ord': 'DESC','action': 'historical_data'})

bs2 = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
tb = bs2.find('table',{"id":"curr_table"})
```

It only returns a piece of the table, not the whole date I just filtered.

I did see the post page below:

[image]

Can anyone help me get the whole table I just filtered?

Comment: Why are you using `POST` if you're not actually submitting any post data?  Also, why are you using a session if you're only performing one action?

Comment: Cause I tried with no session and get, and had the same results. Then I started trying everything

Comment: Where did you get those header values?

Comment: In the photo that I posted

Comment: Those aren't headers, that's form data.  You see how it says "form data"?

Comment: i got 4 table and it have 32 colums,but i can not use regex to filter the value cause encoding problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made two mistakes with your code.

The first one is the url.
You need to use the correct url to request data to investing.com.
Your current `url` is `'https://br.investing.com/commodities/aluminum-historical-data'`

However, when you see inspection and click `'Network'` the `Request URL`is `https://br.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax`.

Your second mistake exists in `s.post(blah)`. As Federico Rubbi referred above, what you coded assigned to `headers` must be assigned to `data` instead.

Now, your mistakes are all resolved. You need to do only one step more. You have to add a dictionary `{'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}` to `your_headers`. Seeing from your code, I can see that you have already checked `Network tab` in `HTML inspection`. So, you are probably able to see why you need `{'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}`.

So the entire code should be as follows.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://br.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax' # Making up for the first mistake.
    your_headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    s.get(url, headers= your_headers)
    c_list = s.cookies.get_dict().items()
    cookie_list = [key+'='+value for key,value in c_list]
    cookie = ','.join(cookie_list)

    your_headers = {**{'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},**your_headers}
    your_headers['Cookie'] = cookie

    data= {} # Your data. Making up for the second mistake.

    response = s.post(url, data= data, headers = your_headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing form *data* as *headers*.

You have to send data with `data` keyworded argument in `request.Session.post`:

```py
with requests.Session() as session:

    url = 'https://br.investing.com/commodities/aluminum-historical-data'

    data = {
        "curr_id": "49768",
        "smlID": "300586",
        "header": "Alumínio Futuros Dados Históricos",
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'st_date': '01/01/2017',
        'end_date': '29/09/2018',
        'interval_sec': 'Daily',
        'sort_col': 'date',
        'sort_ord': 'DESC',
        'action': 'historical_data',
        }

    your_headers = {}  # your headers here

    response = session.post(url, data=data, headers=your_headers)

bs2 = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
tb = bs2.find('table',{"id":"curr_table"})
```

I'd also recommend including your headers (especially `user-agents`) in the POST request because the site could not allow bots. In this case, if you do it, it will be harder to detect the bot.

Comment: It didn't work either. It still returns only till 09/03/2018 (MMDDYYYY)

Comment: Could you please tell me the response status code? Perhaps Beautifulsoup doesn't scrape the page correctly. Try to find the data in _tb.prettify()_.